# Laravel authentication check

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

My navbar should display the *Sign up* and *Login* buttons only if the user is not authenticated, otherwise a *Log out* button.

```
                @if(Auth::check())
                    <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbarButton" href="auth/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a> </li>
                @else
                    <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>
                @endif
```

I know that the user is authenticated, because I get redirected from the login and register pages, but they are still showing in the navbar.

Comment: is there are any error ?

Comment: No, it's working, but after authentication I should see only the log out button

Comment: check the Auth class is Global of not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have got your logic the wrong way around here:

```
@if(Auth::check())
  //this will show if the statement is true (user logged in)
  <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a class="navbarButton" href="auth/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a> </li>
@else
  //this will show if the statement is false (no user logged in)
  <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>
@endif
```

If you reverse it to:

```
@if(Auth::check())
  //this will show if the statement is true (user logged in)      
  <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>
@else
  //this will show if the statement is false (no user logged in)
  <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
  <li><a class="navbarButton" href="auth/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a> </li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one by changing Auth::check() with Auth::user()

```
            @if(Auth::user())
                <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a class="navbarButton" href="auth/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a> </li>
            @else
                <li><a class="navbarButton"  href="auth/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Log out</a></li>
            @endif
```